# Cannot update Bazel to the newest version

Tags: build, tensorflow, ubuntu-14.04, bazel

I have the old version of Bazel that does not match the requirement of building TensorFlow C++ API. Below is the return of `$ bazel version`

```
Build label: 0.3.2
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri Oct 7 17:25:10 2016 (1475861110)
Build timestamp: 1475861110
Build timestamp as int: 1475861110
```

However, when I tried to upgrade it I got nothing new.

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade Bazel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
bazel is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-font-awesome ipython-notebook-common libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common
  libgconf2-4 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libidl-common libidl0 libjs-highlight libjs-jquery-ui
  libjs-marked liborbit-2-0 liborbit2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  ffmpeg gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 libavcodec-dev libavcodec54
  libavformat-dev libavformat54 libavutil-dev libavutil52 libcdt5 libcgraph6
  libcuda1-367 libgraphviz-dev libgvc6 libgvpr2 libpathplan4
  librhythmbox-core8 libswscale-dev libswscale2 libtotem-plparser18 libva1
  libxdot4 nvidia-367 nvidia-367-dev nvidia-opencl-icd-367 rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugins totem totem-common
  totem-mozilla totem-plugins
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
```

The content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` is as below.

```
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

I want to upgrade the installation to version 0.4.5 or higher. Can somebody help?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to do `apt-get update` before? If it does not work, can you post the content of your /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: @DamienMartin-guillerez Yeah, It does not help. The content is updated.

Answer (score 1):

The sources list does not include the Bazel repository, see how to add it [on our installation instructions.](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html#2-add-bazel-distribution-uri-as-a-package-source-one-time-setup)

Once you did it, you should be able to use `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade bazel`